# Only first sentence of caption in LOF / LOT?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

I have some figures and tables which have rather long captions to explain what is going on, but this looks horrible in the list of figures and the list of tables. Can I somehow only use the first sentence of my captions for these? Or can I caption my tables / figures in any other way that I can specify which part should be in the LOF / LOT?

Here an example of a table how I currently do it:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{This is a table with no real data in it. But I decided to put it here anyways. Just for demo purposes. I would like to have only the first sentence in my TOL.} \label{tab:dummy-dum-dum}
    \vspace{2mm}
    \begin{tabular*}{0.9\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc}
        \hline
        \quad \textbf{Site} & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}  \quad \\ \hline
        \quad 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \quad \\ \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Use the optional argument of `\caption` for what you want to see in the lof/lot.

Comment: I am too unfamiliar with LaTeX to actually know, what you mean, sorry....I put it in square brackets before and after the curly brackets, but it did not work?

Comment: Aaaaah, nevermind, thank you! It worked!

Comment: It has to be put before the braces, as usually for optional arguments. Did you recompile more than once? The .aux file has to be changed by the compilation.